# How to access PCF environment variables in spring integration xml or application yml file

Tags: spring-integration, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

I have created an spring integration application and hosted that in PCF (Pivotal Cloud Foundry) environment.

Let us say my manifest file is as follows:

```
applications:
- name: test
  memory: 1024M
  instances: 1
  domain: cfapps.pcf1.vc1.pcf.abc.com
  path: target/test-0.1.0.jar
  health-check-type: http
  health-check-http-endpoint: /health
  env:
   SPRING_LOG_LEVEL:INFO
   param1: value1
   param2: value2
   param3: value3
```

And my application.yml file is as follows:

```
# default properties
logging:
level:
org.springframework.integration: $SPRING_LOG_LEVEL
endpoints:
 autoconfig.sensitive: false
 configprops.sensitive: false
 env.sensitive: false
 loggers.sensitive: false
mq:
  queues:
  validation: queue1
  authorization: queue2
  channel: channel1
  hostName: host1
  port: 100
  queueManager: QMGR
  transportType: 1
  max-concurrent-consumers: $param1
  concurrent-consumers: $param2
  max-messages-per-task: $param3
  idle-consumer-limit: 1
  idle-task-execution-limit: 1
```

My question is how do I access the PCF environment values such as SPRING_LOG_LEVEL, param1, param2 and param3 values present in MANIFEST .yml file inside application .yml or inside spring integration xml file.

Please let me know, if you need further details. Please excuse me if something is not clear as I am new to PCF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those environment variables in your manifest are truly environment variables to the container your boot app is running in and can be accessed as such, either via `System.getenv` or the SpEL `${VARIABLE}` format.

Comment: Correct. In this case that would look like `max-concurrent-consumers: ${param1}`.

Comment: Thanks Josh and Scott for your comments. It seems to work. thanks.